# tree.links() for D3 v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been watching a tutorial on d3 but it shows some outdated code that is no longer used on v4. I was wondering what would be the updated syntax for `var links = tree.links(nodes);` for D3 v4?

If anybody is curious, this is the link to the tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZ6MSHA4FMU&list=PL6il2r9i3BqH9PmbOf5wA5E1wOG3FT22p&index=15

Comment: In v3 it is `tree.links()`, not `tree.link()`. I just edited the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `links()` on the hierarchy.

The [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md) talks about this change:

> To generate an array of {source, target} links for a given hierarchy, use `node.links`; this replaces `tree.links` and similar methods on the other layouts.

Here is a basic demo (use the console of your browser, not the Stack snippet console):

```js
var data = {
  "name": "Eve",
  "children": [{
    "name": "Cain"
  }, {
    "name": "Seth",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Enos"
    }, {
      "name": "Noam"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Abel"
  }, {
    "name": "Awan",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Enoch"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Azura"
  }]
};

var hierarchy = d3.hierarchy(data);

var tree = d3.tree();

var links = tree(hierarchy).links();

console.log(links)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```