# D3 Force-Directed Tree Set Depth of nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I'm working on creating a force-directed tree (this is different from just a regular tree layout!). So far, I have a basic force-directed graph, but I would like to to compute the depth of each of the nodes based on their distance from the root node, then have them gravitate toward a particular y axis towards that depth.

I would like it to look similar to the example [here](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20110921/depth-foci.html)

I already know I have to modify my data to have a hierarchical structure as below:

```
var children_data = {
    "id": "A", 
  "children": [
    {"id": "G"},
    {"id": "E"},
    {"id": "C"},
    {"id": "H"},
    {"id": "B", 
    "children": [
        {"id": "F"},
        {"id": "D"},
    ]},
  ]
};
```

But beyond that I'm missing something. I did try to add the following to my tick function (before that flattening my source data and trying to add a depth):

```
var ky = 1.2 * e.alpha;
    links.forEach(function(d, i) {
      d.target.y += (d.target.depth * 120 - d.target.y) * ky;
    });
```

and to add the depth to each node, where node was defined as flattened(children_data):

```
  function flatten(json) {
  var nodes = [];
  function recurse(node, depth) {
    if (node.children) {
      node.children.forEach(function(child) {
        recurse(child, depth + 1);
      });
    }
    node.depth = depth;
    nodes.push(node);
  }
  recurse(json, 1);
  return nodes;
}
```

But I keep getting errors on the tree layout. My very basic and broken JSFiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/KateJean/dnqj3L5c/). It's specifically breaking on line 70,

```
var links = d3.tree().links(flatten(children_data));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tree.links() for D3 v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47298494/tree-links-for-d3-v4)

Comment: I'm specifically looking for a force-directed graph that is made to look like a tree. The example you linked specifically is for a tree layout. 

I'm looking for a solution like the one here: 
http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20110921/depth-foci.html

Comment: the error is the same - caused by running v2 or v3 code against the v4 library. the solution is to port the script to the current API, while the linked question explains the difference.

Comment: Ah! this definitely got me closer! it got rid of the first error (THANK YOU) but I'm still getting a bug on the 

var ky = 1.2 * e.alpha;
    links.forEach(function(d, i) {
      d.target.y += (d.target.depth * 120 - d.target.y) * ky;
    });

bit of code. I'm getting a 'TypeError:cannot read alpha of undefined'. Am I doing something here that is not kosher with v4?

my JSFiddle has been updated

Comment: that `e` event should be passed into the function scope with `force.on("tick", function(e) {}` ...then it should be defined, within the scope of that function.

Comment: you would think, but I'm still getting the same error. I feel like I'm going crazy here

Comment: `d3-force` might not have been included in the page: https://devdocs.io/d3~4/d3-force https://github.com/d3/d3-force here's a rather current example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/ad70335eeef6d167bc36fd3c04378048